# c# Lambda Query fetching one of the property weirdly null

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SecondMission(string Id)
    {
        CATSDDEntities db = new CATSDDEntities();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var setAlet= db.Setalets.Where(x => x.Aletler.Barkod == Id && x.Bolum == 1).Include(x => x.Aletler.AletAD).Include(x => x.Setler).FirstOrDefault();
        if (setAlet == null)
        {
            return Json("Error, Alet Not Found!", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            setAlet.Bolum = 2;
            db.SaveChanges();
            var MissionTwoSets = db.Setalets.Where(x => x.Bolum == 2 && x.SetId==setAlet.SetId).Include(x => x.Aletler.AletAD).Include(x => x.Setler).GroupBy(x => x.SetId).ToList();
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_SecondMissionSetPartial.cshtml", MissionTwoSets);
        }
    }
```

I am calling this method by ajax

When i call this method first time.. `Aletler` property of `MissionTwoSets` have data.. but when i call this method second time and fetch multiple data.. one of the item get null in `Aletler`([LOOK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1nVG.png)) .. its quite weird.. im using the same code somewhere else using same data and working fine..

Comment: Is the parameter `Id` the same both times you make the call?

Comment: no bro..both time its different

Comment: Well then it's likely a data issue since the value of `MissionTwoSets` depends on `setAlet`, and `setAlet` depends on `Id`.

Comment: @SameerKamran Do you have record in `Aleter` table for AletId 2?

Comment: yes bro.. i have records. same query working good at other place.. im fetching same data somewhere else..

Comment: Just remove `.Include` and create a view model for your view, and map your real data to view model, it is M-V-C. BTW, `Linq.GroupBy(x => x.SetId).ToList()` returns `List<IGrouping<Tkey,Setalet>>`, not a `List<Setalet>`

Comment: only difference is that..im calling this method with ajax and im doing  db.SaveChanghes() just before fetching data in this case.

Comment: Yes im getting the data in List<IGrouping<int?, Setalet>> ..but its not an issue..

Comment: ViewModel will save you then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Include`s are ignored (have no effect) in `GroupBy` queries, so normally the navigation properties would be `null`.

However what you see is a result of the context tracking. Since you first load a single entity, it's eager loaded properties are not `null`. Then when you execute the `GroupBy` which result includes the already loaded (tracked) entity, then EF reuses that instance and hence it would still have navigation properties populated. All other entities would have `null` navigation properties due to the aforementioned "ignored includes".

Since the `GroupBy` query like this makes no sense to be executed server side (has no SQL equivalent), the solution is to execute the `GroupBy` part client side (by inserting the typical `AsEnumerable()` before it), thus keeping the includes in effect:

```
var MissionTwoSets = db.Setalets
    .Where(x => x.Bolum == 2 && x.SetId==setAlet.SetId)
    .Include(x => x.Aletler.AletAD)
    .Include(x => x.Setler)
    .AsEnumerable() // <-- switch to LINQ to Objects
    .GroupBy(x => x.SetId)
    .ToList();
```